# Background Images in Android ListView are not Showing Up

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-imageview, android-xml

I have a custom `ListView` and `adapter`, and this is the code for my `listview_item.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17.0dip"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:paddingTop="17.0dip"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24.0dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="-3.0dip"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textColor="#ffaaaaaa"
        android:textSize="13.0dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRanks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Ranks" >
    </Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to set an image as the background of each `list` item, but when I call `imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);`, I get a `listview` that looks like this: [image]. You can see that the image fills the entire `width` of the `listview`, but not the `height`. How do I get the image to fill the `listview`'s height as well?

By the way, this is the intended background image: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ImageView, instead of

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

use

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

I'd also remove the attribute

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Comment: Hmmm the `listview` looks the exact same after that change. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If the image is the same for all items... set it once in the xml layout rather than setting it by code.

Comment: Unfortunately, the image is different for each list item. That's why I'm changing it programmatically

Comment: OK, so it makes sense. Just as an experiment (not to do in practice): what happens if you force the height to be as tall as the image in px?

Comment: Yeah but the image is still cropped/condensed. Do you have any other potential solutions? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What If you remove the scaleType attribute from the ImageView? It does not appear to be helpful in this context

Comment: Now the image does not fill the `listview's` width as well. [Here is a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/qS9WOgw.png)

Comment: How big is the image in relation to the device? What is its resolution in dpi? Did you use the right drawable folder? All things that matter.

Comment: I am lazy-loading [this image](http://i.imgur.com/GG7cLZZ.jpg) using a drawable manager I found online. [Here is the link to the DrawableManager](http://stackoverflow.com/a/559781/1467730).

Comment: 72 dpi... 550*137. It should go in the xhdpi folder, but it should be brought to 320 dpi, if you want it to scale well on other devices. Now, a quick experiment before I go for dinner: try setting it in code by using imageView.setBackground(drawable); // set it as background, so it's automatically stretched